# calculating max and min expressible values for floating point number rep

Tags: computer-science

i want to figure out why expressible numbers in the IEEE floating point standard is 10^+38 - -10^38 (and similarly for the +ve). most textbooks just make this statement of fact, im grappling with why. ie. how would you calc this range?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are talking abount [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) single-precision (32-bit) floating point representation.
In this format, maximum value of the exponent is 127. The representation is base-2, thus maximum possible value is about 2^127. Let's [convert it to decimal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Base.html): 127 * log(2) / log(10) ≈ 38.23. That's why max value representable by a 32-bit float is approx. 10^38. You can find more details on the IEEE 754 floats in the linked Wikipedia article.

Comment: I don't understand how you calculate that. The value a float takes is `(-1)^s * (1.0+0.M) * 2^e-127`. Where `e` is the actual 8 bit sequence stored. The way to maximize that expression is to set e to the max value it cna be stored which is 127. That leads to an exponent of zero not 127. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @CharlieParker You lost one bit.The largest value an 8-bit fiteld can represent is 255, not 127. So the largest exponent should have been 255-127=128, except that the all-ones exponent field is reserved to indicate special values (NaNs and infinities).